# PM PRO addon package check user access to a specific post

Tags: plugins

I have pmpro addon package installed and need to check whether user has access to post and then display text depending on that. Here's the code

```
 function members_only() {

   if( is_user_logged_in() ) {

     $user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
     $post_id[]=array(361,369,367,371,476); 

          if( pmproap_hasAccess($user_id, $post_id[0]) ) {
          ?>

              <style>

                .pricing-button {
                   display:none;
                 }
              </style>

          <?php 
        }

     }
   }
     add_action('wp_head','members_only');
```

But not functioning, no error as well. Thank in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer figured out,dont know exactly what was wrong but just entered the ID( i.e 376) in each section instead of $post_id[0] array.
Would be glad to know if something was wrong in the code I posted in my question.
Thanks

**EDIT**

Was using

```
$post_id[] = array(361,369,367,371,476);
```

instead of

```
$post_id = array(361,369,367,371,476);
```